# Don't I need a double bracket when I am accessing a column to apply a lamda function in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda

The code below is taking a sentence (character string ) from the "text" column from a DataFrame and replacing any non-alpha numeric characters (i.e.#,?. 1. etc) with a space. I always thought
That since "text" is a column, I would need to use double brackets on each side. When I add that I get the error shwon below. Wouldn't single brackets refer to rows? Since "text" is a column
don't I need double brackets?

```
data['text'] = data['text'].apply((lambda x: re.sub\
('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]','',x)))
```

in (x)
24 #remove special characters
25 data[['text']] = data[['text']].apply((lambda x: re.sub
---> 26 ('[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]','',x)))
27

~\Anaconda3\lib\re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
190     a callable, it's passed the Match object and must return
191     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 192     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
193
194 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: ('expected string or bytes-like object', 'occurred at index text')

Comment: You really don't need to use lambda's at all here.  Look at using the string accessor in pandas.  [pandas working with text](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html)  and replace in the [pandas string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#string-methods)

Comment: Thanks Scott, but my question was really aimed at finding out why I do not need double brackets to access a column (and why double brackets gives me an error).

Comment: With single bracks you are passing a pd.Series in to the apply function, when you use double brackets you are passing a pd.Dataframe to the apply function.  If your lambda function is written to hand a pd.Series then the double brackets will error out when passing a single column dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Single brackets yeilds a pd.Series and double brackets yeilds a single column dataframe.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':[1,2,3,4]})

type(df['Col1']) # <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

type(df[['Col1']]) # <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

You're lambda function is designed to hand a pd.Series.

Let's write a custom function to analyze what is passed.

```
def f(x):
    print(type(x))
    return x

df['Col1'].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

The class 'int' show that when calling apply on a pd.Series, each element in that series is passed to the function in apply.

Versus a single column dataframe:

```
df[['Col1']].apply(f)
```

Output:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

This shows that each dataframe column (a  pd.Series) is passed to the function in apply.